# how to fetch data without reloading the page from firebase database in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have already configured firebase settings here is a piece of my code :

```
const [PostList, SetPostList] = useState([])

  const db = getFirestore(firebaseConfig)
  const q = query(collection(db, "posts"))
  const querySnapshot = getDocs(q)

  useEffect(()=>{
  querySnapshot.then(data=> data.forEach(post => {
    SetPostList([post.data()])
    console.log(PostList)
  }))
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer:

```
const db = getFirestore(firebaseConfig)
    const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, querySnapshot => {

      const cities = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          cities.push(doc.data());
      });
      SetPostList(cities)
      
    });
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `SetPostList` outside the loop:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let result = [];
  querySnapshot.then((data) => {
    data.forEach((post) => {
      result.push(post.data());
      console.log(PostList);
    });
    SetPostList(result);
  });
}, []);
```